# How to express an imaginary number in method argument in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nan

"nan" and "nani" is being displayed in my output. I have discovered that this stands for "not a number", but I am not able to see where I am going wrong, and whether my problem lies with my lack of understanding of Objective-C, or imaginary numbers, or something else.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Complex: NSNumber

-(void) setReal: (double) a;
-(void) setImaginary: (double) b;
-(void) print; // display as a + bi
-(double) real;
-(double) imaginary;

@end

@implementation Complex
{
    double real;
    double imaginary;
}
-(void) setReal: (double) a
{
    real = a;
}
-(void) setImaginary: (double) b
{
    imaginary = b;
}
-(void) print
{
    NSLog (@"%f x %fi = %f", real, imaginary, real * imaginary);
}
-(double) real
{
    return real;
}
-(double) imaginary
{
    return imaginary;
}
@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        Complex *complex1 = [[Complex alloc] init];

        // Set real and imaginary values for first complex sum:
        [complex1 setReal: 2];
        [complex1 setImaginary: 3 * (sqrt(-1))];

        // Display first complex number sum with print method:
        NSLog (@"When a = 2 and b = 3, the following equation a x bi =");
        [complex1 print];

        //Display first complex number sum with getter method:
        NSLog (@"When a = 2 and b = 3, the following equation 
        a x bi = %f x %fi = %fi", [complex1 real], [complex1 imaginary], 
        [complex1 real] * [complex1 imaginary]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
[complex1 setImaginary: 3 * (sqrt(-1))];
```

The result of `sqrt(-1)` is `NaN`, `sqrt()` does not return "complex" numbers in any sense.

To set the imaginary part of your `Complex` object, you just set

```
[complex1 setImaginary: 3];
```

(`setImaginary:` expects a `double` argument, which makes sense because the imaginary part of a complex number is a *real* number.)

*Remark:* I have no idea what you want to achieve with your `print` method, but it does not
print `a + bi` as stated at the top of your program.

Comment: Martin,Thanks so much for your response. I am trying to answer the Exercise 4.6 in S.Kochan's Programming in Objective-C book. I get the feeling I may have misunderstood things in the previous chapters and need to go back and revise the 'print' method section. Thanks for the help - it is tough going coming from a no-previous-knowledge-of-programming, and trying to work through a book (great as it is) that doesn't supply the answers!

Comment: @VioladaGamba: You are welcome. I don't have that book, so I cannot tell you what is expected. Perhaps `print` should just print a description of the object: `NSLog(@"%f + %fi", real, imaginary)` ? You should also have a look at Objective-C "properties", the current compilers can create the setter/getter methods automatically. - Note that you can "accept" an answer that helped by clicking on the check mark. That marks the problem as solved and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Great, many thanks, new to this forum today, and loving it. Really appreciate the advice and help. Now understand where I went wrong. Will check out Ob-C "properties".

Answer (score 1):

Your NaNs come from `sqrt(-1)`.

Do you want to implement your own complex types? C99 adds them, so unless you're using an ancient Objective-C compiler you'll be able to do something like this:

```
#include <complex.h>

double complex c = 3 * 2 I;
double r = creal(c);
double i = cimag(c);
```

There's some useful documentation and examples in the GNU libc manual: [Complex Numbers](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Complex-Numbers.html).

Comment: Matt, thanks for the help and link - looks good. I can see I have an even steeper learning curve ahead of me than I initially realised - no surprises there. Claire